# ERM diagram, decompose two entities

Tags: sql, database, relationship

As this statement, `Parts are stored in more than one warehouse`. Obviously, this is a `m:n` relationship, but I need to decompose this `m:n` relationship to **two** `1:m` relationship. Such as `Parts -> ?? <- Warehouse`. So Could someone tell me what is the link between parts and warehouse?

Comment: It is called a junction table.  I would called the table either `PartsWarehouse` or `WarehouseParts`.

Comment: WarehouseParts makes a lot more sense to me. You had a WarehouseID and PartID to it.